# removing data by value from a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had created two arrays to store an array of data into local storage. I'm storing it by creating an array of array. But not able to remove the value.

```
 `var divMappingArray = new Array();
 var data = new Array();

 data[0] = {"ID": 123, "Name": "temp" };
 divMappingArray.push(data[0]);
 data[1] = {"ID": 23, "Name": "temp1" };
 divMappingArray.push(data[1]);`

 localStorage.setItem('zoneObject', JSON.stringify(divMappingArray));
```

I'm saving this into local storage, but I need to remove a value based on name or id. I      tried looping it and remove the item, but this is not working for me.

```
  $.each($.parseJSON(retrievedObject), function(i, value){
            delete value.ID[i];
    });
```

Parsing the array value by retrieving from local storage and want to add the updated data into local storage back.
While removing i want to remove the whole set of array value both ID and name, the retrieved data length will be reduced after the removal.

Comment: I think the second `data[0] =` should be `data[1] =`.

Comment: @Barmar : yes it is 1 , im updated the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying the aray, you need to update the local storage

```
var rarray = $.parseJSON(retrievedObject);
$.each(rarray, function (i, value) {
    if (value.ID == 23) {
        rarray.splice(i, 1);
        return false;
    }
});
localStorage.setItem('zoneObject', JSON.stringify(rarray));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t3zDM/)

Comment: rarray length is same before and after removing.

Comment: @Rosh you are not removing anything from `rarray`, only a property inside the array objects are deleted

Comment: i want to remove the whole {"ID": 23, "Name": "temp1" }; based on id, sorry my question was not clear i guess.

Comment: can i get key also in the loop tried with key.Name, not wrking that

Comment: @Rosh which key... if you want to access name `value.Name`